# Octave: make it as much MATLAB-compatible as possible

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to implement a couple of algorithms in `MATLAB`(homework), however I want to use `GNU Octave` instead. But I'd like to turn off any `octave` extensions, and basically turn it into FOSS-version of `MATLAB`. What settings should I change? What command-line options should I provide when executing `octave` program?

PS: I am aware of `--traditional` command-line option, although it doesn't seem to do much.

PPS: Any suggestions are welcome. If following your advice requires, for example, rebuilding `octave` from source, let it be.

Comment: I see that you have opened up a bounty about this asking for an octave/matlab expert because my answer was ok and you want something more detailed. I'm an Octave developer and the maintainer of Octave Forge (that's the project with all the octave packages), I thought the answer was pretty complete. Could you explain then exactly what you are asking? With an example maybe?

Comment: Your answer is great. I also agree it is to simply not use certain syntax, but it requires knowledge of what to avoid. So I'm still wondering why nobody implemented even some sort of `--lint` switch. Is it just because nobody really needed it, or because of difficulty, or because of some policies?

Comment: Second thing, I used octave a little bit, and noticed that octave has `qp` function while MATLAB has `quadprog`. I am no expert in this field, but quadratic programming seems basic task to me. So, another question: why are there differently named functions for doing similar things? And also, why there are no compatibility layer which can make porting scripts easier?

Comment: It just puzzles me a bit that octave project seems to treat incompatibility with MATLAB as bugs, yet have no up-to-date tools for porting scripts MATLAB<->Octave

Comment: Too many questions to answer in a comment (come to #octave in freenode) but basically:there can be no such flag because Octave uses its own syntax internally. `quadprog` is not in Matlab, it's in the optimization toolbox.If you care about it,please report a bug and maybe submit a patch making it compatible.May be because no one needed to implement a compatible version before.Rememeber,Octave only has the features that its users care to implement. Also, sometimes Octave implements things before Matlab (structs for example), and then needs to "fix" to be compatible. Use a text editor for Matlab.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I think I grasped the core idea of how octave and matlab are related.

Comment: I have just found out you can turn on warnings for non compatible. Try to set `warning ('on', 'Octave:matlab-incompatible')`. You can this to your octaverc file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside using the `--traditional` option there's nothing you can do. Simply do not use the extra syntax that Octave offers. After all, Matlab syntax is a subset of the GNU Octave language, and it's up to you to use that subset only.

**EDIT:** It's not the answer you'd like but there's a good reason why that's an impossible task (by impossible, I mean very difficult. The only option is really to just fork Octave and change it until it's an exact clone. And you don't want to do it, trust me). Imagine the following very example. Octave has the functions 'rows' and 'columns' but Matlab does not. If you changed Octave so that these functions no longer exist, all other Octave functions that use them (I'm guessing a lot), will also stop working.

Others before you have successfully convinced their professors to accept homework written in Octave though, just make sure you at least try to write compatible code.

**EDIT 2:** I'll try to explain by comparing this situation with pianos (seems like a very good comparison). You can buy a piano with 85 or 88 keys. Now imagine that Matlab is a piano with 85 keys while Octave is a piano with 88 keys (if you want, also imagine that Matlab has 3 pedals while Octave only has 2 pedals). The only difference between the two pianos is that one has a slightly larger tonal range, i.e., it can play a few more tones (from the 3 extra keys). But when you play a C4 on a piano with 85 keys and a C4 on a piano with 88 keys, the sound is the same, they are the same note. The notes are the functions and keywords you have available. They are the same. A note in one piano is the same note on the other.

Now, if you are a composer writing music, you may want to take that in consideration. Just don't write any piece of music that requires those extra keys. The music will be the same in both types of pianos. If you have a piano with 88 keys, you will not chop off the 3 extra keys because you want it to be compatible with the 85 keys pianos. You simply don't play those keys. A piano with 88 keys is compatible with a piano with 85 keys, in the same way that Octave is compatible with Matlab.

If you want a guide to remind you that you can't use those extra keys, I'd guess you could put some red tape on them to remind you not to use them. Similarly, use Octave with a text editor that has different syntax highlight for Octave and Matlab so it will highlight incorrectly when you use syntax that is not part of Matlab. Aside that, there is nothing you can do (unless you count forking the Octave project, request Mathworks to implement them in Matlab or implementing them yourself. I don't mean this as rude sarcasm, just trying to be exhaustive).

For sake of completion, yes Octave has not implemented all Matlab things yet but it's moving that way as people develop it. It's not a static project (just take a look at the [NEWS](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/default/NEWS) file for the development branch for example), things get implemented as the people who need them develop them. And some functions do behave differently but those are bugs you can [report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave) (and even fix since after all it's free and open source). Such incompatibilities are not there for the sake of annoying users. They are there because no one has reported or fixed them. Plus most of them are for incorrectly or undocumented Matlab features.

**EDIT 3:** you can also turn on the matlab incompatible warnings (which are off by default). Run `warning ('on', 'Octave:matlab-incompatible')`. You can leave this on your `.octaverc` file. To see more warnings look into `warning_ids`.

Comment: Do you see my point? :) BTW, a fork is really hard to get going, especially in this case I reckon. It would be far easier at this point to create a compatibility library (containing hundreds of little things like `function R=rows(A), R=size(A,1); end`)...or does such a thing already exist?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis no. I don't see the problem, it's up to the person that writes the code to not use that extra syntax. And that's very easy to do if you use a text editor with different syntax highlights for Octave and Matlab (such as gedit -- since early last year only). There's a package in Octave-Forge, oct2mat, that tries to convert code from Octave in Matlab but never tried it myself. It's completely unmaintained though, no one has touched it for ages.

Comment: Homework: sure, use Octave. Most professional life: not a chance in hell. Which is better to learn, Matlab or Octave? That depends entirely on your immediate career plans. I you're learning Octave, you'll have to also defend why you're NOT learning Python/SciPy/NumPy/Matplotlib, which has a far larger community AFAIK.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I use Octave for image analysis and perl for bioinformatics. The reason why I use Octave is that there's a lot of code written for it but not so much for those that you mentioned. Yes, most of it was written for Matlab but luckily, it runs fine in Octave. I really don't see what's your problem with the extra Octave syntax. It's optional and doesn't break compatibility. And this is probably not the place to discuss it.

Comment: No it's not. Are you ever in chat?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis either ##matlab (the double # is not a typo) or #octave on freenode

Comment: @carandraug, you didn't give the answer he wanted, you gave the answer he needed.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is better to use a GUI that does it for you. I personally use [Xoctave](http://www.xoctave.com)
due to its support and Matlab like interface.